# Is it "When the wicked" or "devil a wicked" in "Rivers of Babylon: Boney M"?

Tags: pronunciation, lyrics, syllables

I am studying English with the song "Rivers of Babylon: Boney M". I can't hear well the "When the wicked" part. It sounds like "devil a wicked" to me, but the text is "When the wicked" in the lyrics. Is the lyrics' "When the wicked" correct, or what is the real word of the part?

Please explain the pronunciation of the part and the real word.

> By the rivers of Babylon, there we sat down
> Yeah we wept, when we remembered Zion
>
> When the wicked
> Carried us away in captivity
> Required from us a song

Comment: Hi hohyun.  Welcome to ELL!  Music and the clarification of lyrics are not the focus at ELL.  There is great leeway in what the written lyrics from the website say and what words come out of the singer's mouth when they sing those lyrics.  Questions on ELL are focused on things such as meaning, usage, and grammar.

Comment: It's almost certainly "when the wicked". Do you have some question about English language, or is there some reason relating to English grammar/usage that you think it cannot be "when the wicked"?

Comment: [correction: What are the real lyrics etc.]

Comment: Note that you can easily google song lyrics. https://www.google.com/search?q=rivers+of+babylon+lyrics&oq=rivers+of+babylon+l&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBwgBEAAYgAQyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQABiABDIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQLhiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABNIBCDkwODlqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Google's result gives "There" instead of "When". From listening to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSxQJUv1e8k I believe this transcription is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I firmly believe they sing '**there the wicked**'. It sounds a bit like 'Dere da wick-ed'. You should understand that (1) Boney M was really a German band, (2) the singers came from the West Indies, and (3) the words you heard were sung with Jamaican pronunciation. The linked video is a live performance; the words may be clearer in [the studio version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSxQJUv1e8k).

> There the wicked
> Carried us away in captivity
> Requiring of us a song
> Now how shall we sing the Lord's song in a strange land?

The song is based on Psalm 137 in the Christian Bible. In English that psalm is generally known as "By the rivers of Babylon", which is how its first words are translated in the King James Version of the Bible. Its Latin title is "Super flumina Babylonis".

> 1 By the rivers of Babylon, there we sat down, yea, we wept, when we
> remembered Zion.
>
> 2 We hanged our harps upon the willows in the midst thereof.
>
> **3 For there they that carried us away captive required of us a song;
> and they that wasted us required of us mirth, saying, Sing us one of
> the songs of Zion.**
>
> **4 How shall we sing the Lord's song in a strange land?**
>
> 5 If I forget thee, O Jerusalem, let my right hand forget her cunning.
>
> 6 If I do not remember thee, let my tongue cleave to the roof of my
> mouth; if I prefer not Jerusalem above my chief joy.
>
> 7 Remember, O Lord, the children of Edom in the day of Jerusalem; who
> said, Rase it, rase it, even to the foundation thereof.
>
> 8 O daughter of Babylon, who art to be destroyed; happy shall he be,
> that rewardeth thee as thou hast served us.
>
> 9 Happy shall he be, that taketh and dasheth thy little ones against
> the stones.

You can find 'lyrics sites' that show either 'when the wicked' and 'there the wicked' but I hear 'there' on the record and also that agrees with Psalm 137, from which the song is derived.

Answer (score -2):

It is very clear that at 1:27 in this video the singer sings "then the wicked" rather than "when the wicked":

https://youtu.be/l3QxT-w3WMo?t=87